# Unable to upload bundled json from FHIRBASE using .create function

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have a bundled json file from FHIRBASE stored locally. Just trying to upload it using .create function which works fine with individual resource files. But using it for bundled json gives the following error
[part of error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxrq2.png).

PS: Trying to do all this in jupyter.

Uploading it using something like: `fhirbase --host localhost -p 5432 -d customdata -U postgres -W ****** --fhir=3.3.0 load -m insert`
uploads it but history tables are not populated when same data is uploaded with minor changes.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you're using the latest FHIRBASE build. You can download the lastest nightly build here: https://github.com/fhirbase/fhirbase/releases/tag/nightly-build

The latest Fhirbase build should take individual resources from bundles and insert them individually. Try to load them again, and if it fails, please provide me the full command you run, the output, and if it's possible, sample files you're trying to load.

Thanks,
Mike.